# onscrollbottom и onscrolltop

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно так чтобы если скролят вверх выполнялась одна функция а при скролле вниз, другая. Есть ли такое событие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cобытия такого нет. Но вы можете создать переменную содержащую в себе последнюю Y-координату. Например, так:

```
var scrolling = {
 lastYScroll : 0,

 scroll : function () {
  var currentScrolling = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  if (currentScrolling > lastYScroll) {
   //скроллинг вниз
  } else if (currentScrolling < lastYScroll) {
   //скроллинг вверх
  }

  lastYScroll = currentScrolling;
 }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", scrolling.scroll);
```